# Enable horizontal and vertical scrolling on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a Site with the following structure:

- You enter the site and can scroll down from section1 to two.
- Then, you need to decide if you scroll again one section more down or start scrolling right.

This is what I got for scrolling:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/equalsound/zjxum4j3/)

Smooth horizontal works fine but I can't get the vertical working and you can scroll top on section 2 and 3, but there shouldn't be anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite sure if you are looking for something like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(window).scrollLeft()` in jQuery and then add or subtract the height or the width of the viewport:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.scrollDown').click(function(){
        var scrollDown = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollDown + 'px'}, 600);
    });

    $('.scrollRight').click(function(){
        var scrollRight = $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: scrollRight + 'px'}, 600);
    });

    $('.scrollUp').click(function(){
        var scrollUp = $(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollUp + 'px'}, 600);
    });

    $('.scrollLeft').click(function(){
        var scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft() - $(window).width();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: scrollLeft + 'px'}, 600);
    });

});
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
width: 200vw;
overflow: hidden;
}

section {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}

button {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 48vh;
left: 48vw;
width: 160px;
}

button:nth-last-of-type(3) {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 38vh;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 48vh;
}

button:nth-of-type(3) {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 58vh;
}

.x1y2, .x2y2 {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}

.x1y3 {
clear:left;
}

.x1y1 {
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.x1y2 {
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.x2y2 {
background-color: rgb(0,127,0);
}

.x1y3 {
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="x1y1">
<button class="scrollDown" type="button">Scroll Down</button>
</section>

<section class="x1y2">
<button class="scrollUp" type="button">Scroll Up</button>
<button class="scrollRight" type="button">Scroll Right</button>
<button class="scrollDown" type="button">Scroll Down</button>
</section>

<section class="x2y2">
<button class="scrollLeft" type="button">Scroll Left</button>
</section>

<section class="x1y3">
<button class="scrollUp" type="button">Scroll Up</button>
</section>
```